# Laravel checkbox implementation for updating database

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, laravel-5.3

I've been trying to make an attendance management system in Laravel.
In the attendance view,when a checkbox is checked ,the controller function is supposed to increment the appropriate database column.

I've been having some issues.Here's my code:
views:

```
<div class="container">
<!--<div class="row">-->
    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
       <div class="panel panel-default">

            <div class="panel-heading">Take Attendance</div>
            <h4><center>Teacher: {{ auth()->user()->name}}</center></h4>
            <div class="form-inline">

             @foreach ($second as $sec)
                            <br>
                          <div class = "form-group">

                            {{$sec->Roll }}
                            &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
                            {{ $sec->Name}}
                            </div>
                            <div class = "form-group">
                            <!--{{Form::checkbox('agree') }}-->
                            <input tabindex="1" type="checkbox" value="{{$sec->Roll}}"  name=""  />
                            </div>
             @endforeach

             </div>
             <br>
            <form action ="report_generate&<?php echo $name ?>" method = "post" enctype = "multipart/form-data" >
            <!--<input type = "hidden" name = "_token" value = "{{{ csrf_token() }}}"/>-->
             <div class = "form-group">
             <input type="submit" value= "Submit">
            <center><a href ="/home/report&<?php echo $name ?>">Report</a></center>
             </div>
            </form>

            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Controller(for submit button):

```
public function report_generate($tabu)

{

$year = DB::table('sub')->select('Year')-
>where('sub.Subject_Name','=',$tabu)->get();

$sub_id = DB::table('sub')->select('Subject_Id')-
>where('sub.Subject_Name','=',$tabu)->get();

        ob_start();
        echo $year;
        $output=ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();

        if ( $output=='[{"Year":1}]')
        {

                $req = "first";
        }
        elseif ( $output=='[{"Year":2}]')
        {

                $req = "second";
        }
        elseif ( $output=='[{"Year":3}]')
        {

                $req = "third";
        }
        elseif ( $output=='[{"Year":4}]')
        {

                $req = "fourth";
        }

        $final = DB::table($req)->get();
        //dd($final);
        //$columns = Schema::getColumnListing($req);
        //dd($sub_id);
        ob_start();
        echo $sub_id;
        //dd($sub_id);
        $va=ob_get_clean();
        $va = stripslashes($va);
        $txt = rtrim($va,"}]");
        $txt = ltrim($txt,"[{Subject_Id:");
        $txt = ltrim($txt,"Subject_Id:");
        $txt = explode(":",$txt);
        $txt = str_replace('"','', $txt);
        //dd($txt[1]);

        $columns = Schema::getColumnListing($req);
        //dd($columns);
        //dd($txt);
        foreach ($columns as $col)
        {
                //dd("Y");
                if($col == $txt[1])
                {
                        $got=DB::table($req)->select($col)->get();
                        //dd($got);
                        foreach($got as $g)
                                {

                                        //want to increment that cell value

                                }
                }
        }
}
```

Comment: What *issues* have you been having? :)

Comment: off topic but please follow a good book to learn the conventions of MVC you are mixing a lot of core php stuff in your framework. I am not criticizing just suggesting.

Comment: The issue is that, I can't seem to increment the specific cell of a particular column. Also, I cannot pass the value of the checkbox. Please help.

Comment: @lesssugar The issue is that, I can't seem to increment the specific cell of a particular column. Also, I cannot pass the value of the checkbox. Please help

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your checkboxs are outside of the form divs which is an issue. You also seem to be skipping over the Laravel features, for example having a Sub Model you can call on, or using the Request facade. Also not sure why you're using ob for those string comparisons (might actually want to look at Switch for that long elseif block) Lastly, you might want to to use a raw DB statement to do the increments within a SQL query

```
DB::statement("UPDATE " . $table . " set " . $column . " to " . $column . " + 1 WHERE id IN (" implode(', ', $ids) . ')")
```

Comment: I'm still not able to pass the value of the checkbox to the controller. then only,I can use this statement.

Comment: Then that is likely because your checkbox is outside of your form tags. 
<form ... > needs to be put higher, when using panels, I like to put it just inside the outermost panel div, so right after: <div class="panel panel-default">. Then you can put </form> at the end of the panel div.  Only the inputs within those will be included in the Post request.